# "Checkout" modifies files in Git for deployment

Tags: git

So I decided to install the Windows version of Git locally (I do Unix web dev but also .NET dev, so seems circuitous to run Git on UNIX for my .NET projects).

For the web development work I'll just deploy it myself with FTP, but wanted to ask: is there any convenient way to have Git build a directory structure for a subset of files, such as all the files in a particular branch?

For example: say I have this web server file structure

```
/public_html/index.php
/public_html/config.php
/public_html/style/style.css
/public_html/style/typography.css
```

locally I modify only index.php and style.css

it would be nice if there was some way to "checkout" these files and have it build their full file paths. In Visual Source Safe, it actually stores all your files in the VSS database. So you can delete you working copy, and checkout a few files, and it will write them to your working directory in their appropriate directory structures. Is there something like that in GIT? if so then I could just export the modified files and upload the root folder (/public_html) to the server

Comment: git has functions to do most anything you want.  Please describe what you are really trying to achieve at a higher level.  We can probably recommend a git approach with branches, forks, clone and the like but we need to know your overall goal first.

Comment: For example if you have files you want to save you can make a branch for them, do work there, copy the directories as needed to another directory, etc. it all depends on what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: I think I explained what i'm really trying to do in sufficient detail, but I'll be happy to elaborate if you could tell which area needs more details. 

Basically I want to write out a subset of files so I can upload them to my server. If I make a branch for a new feature I'm adding to my web app, and I touch 5 or 6 files during that development, I don't want to have to upload my entire site (X GB in size). So I'd like to just 'export' from Git, the files in that branch, so I can easily upload (FTP) them to the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`git diff-tree`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html).  You can use it compare the state of two commits' trees and determine what files have changed.  For example:

```
git diff-tree --name-status -r `git merge-base master mybranch` mybranch
```

will show you the name and status of any files that have changed.  You can also use `--name-only` instead of `--name-status` if you are sure that things like deleted files will still be handled correctly.

(Of course, command substitution with `` is a UNIX-shell construct; on Windows you may need to use something like FOR /F.)

You can then pass the files listed by this command to `git checkout`.  If you want to check files out into a separate directory, you can use the `--work-tree` parameter:

```
git --work-tree=path/to/build checkout mybranch -- file file file...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the index's most recent copy of any `file` with:

```
git checkout HEAD -- <file>
```

So if you deleted a file in your working directory, you could "restore" it with that command.

Comment: please review the whole question. I'm not sure if your really got the big picture. Happy to answer any questions.

Comment: @MaxHodges Afraid I'm not quite sure what you're attempting to do. "Exporting from git" doesn't make much sense in this context, as git tracks changes to a working directory of files. If you change files in a working directory, you can `tar` and ftp them without touching git at all.

Comment: the idea is that while I might have 10,000 files in my working directory, I might have only changed 5 or 10 to implement a new feature. Just wondering if there would be anyway to 'checkout' or 'write out' only those files affected during development on a branch, so I could easily upload them. Rather than uploading all 10,000 files.